How to delete all rows hidden by user
Every end of the month I duplicate a tab with multiple hidden rows, then delete all those hidden rows from the duplicate tab. For that purpose I modified the following code of Tanaike, the code running without any error, but all hidden rows still there.
Please advice what correction should be made for the code.
Here is the modified code:
function deleteHiddenRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gid);
  const sheetName = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName(tab);
  const lastRow = sheetName.getLastRow();
  const sheetId = sheetName.getSheetId();
  const fields = "sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByUser)),properties/sheetId)";
  const rowMetadata = SheetsV4.Spreadsheets.get(gid, { fields: fields }).sheets[0].data[0].rowMetadata;
  const requests = rowMetadata.reduce((ar, { hiddenByUser }, i) => {
    if (hiddenByUser && i > 0 && i + 1 < lastRow) ar.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "ROWS" } } });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  SheetsV4.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests}, gid);
}


@Alma_Matters provided a code that solved my problem, if my file only had 1 tab.
Since my file had more than 1 tab (my fault for not providing the exact condition at the first place), the code won't work as what I want.
Then I did some troubleshooting to the original code, and finally found a workaround.
Following is the code that solved my real case.
const gid = '###'; //spreadsheet id
const tab = 'tab name'; //tab name

function deleteHiddenRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gid);
  const sheetName = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName(tab);
  const lastRow = sheetName.getLastRow();
  const sheetId = sheetName.getSheetId();
  const idx = sheetName.getIndex()-1; //get the index of the tab
  const fields = "sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByUser)),properties/sheetId)";
  const rowMetadata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(gid, { fields: fields}).sheets[idx].data[0].rowMetadata;
  const requests = rowMetadata.reduceRight((ar, { hiddenByUser }, i) => {
    if (hiddenByUser && i > 0 && i + 1 < lastRow) {
      ar.push({ 
        deleteDimension: { 
          range: { 
            sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "ROWS" 
          } 
        } 
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if(requests.length > 0){
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests}, gid);
  }
}


Delete Hidden Rows
I've tried your code and made some minor changes and this is what works on my end. It seems that the issue is coming from the behavior of Reduce Array Method and I changed it. Please refer to the script below.
Code:
  function deleteHiddenRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = 'Replace it with your actual SpreadsheetID';
  const sheetName = 'Replace it with your duplicate sheet tab';
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const fields = "sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByUser)),properties/sheetId)";

  // Fetch row metadata using Sheets API v4
  const rowMetadataResponse = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { fields: fields }); //For some reason SheetsV4.Spreadsheets.get doesnt work in my end.
  const rowMetadata = rowMetadataResponse.sheets[0].data[0].rowMetadata;

  // Build batch update requests to delete hidden rows
  const requests = [];

  for (let i = rowMetadata.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (rowMetadata[i].hiddenByUser) {
      requests.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId: sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: 'ROWS' } } });
    }
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, spreadsheetId);
}

Instead of using this part of your code
const requests = rowMetadata.reduce((ar, { hiddenByUser }, i) => {
    if (hiddenByUser && i > 0 && i + 1 < lastRow) ar.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "ROWS" } } });
    return ar;
  }, []);

Try using this one:
const requests = [];

    for (let i = rowMetadata.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (rowMetadata[i].hiddenByUser) {
          requests.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId: sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: 'ROWS' } } });
        }
      }

I used the for loop to iterate over rowMetadata for data ranges. This reverse iteration prevents issues and ensures that deleting rows doesn’t affect the indices of rows yet to be processed.
Sample Output
Before
After
Reference:
For Loop
Reduce
Sheets.HideRow()
